# Python Selenium Wait for user input and then pass to selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I need to create a python web-scraper to collect some site data.

However, the target site only will grant access after a single CAPTCHA is fulfilled (a one time event)

I was thinking if it is possible to use a simple web-scraper script (like selenium) to:

1. make a first contact to the target site
2. get the CAPTCHA img, display it to the user use a user input to ask the CAPTCHA value
3. then send the user input back to the site, in order to continue navigation.

i'm lost at the 2nd step, can anyone help me?

Comment: It would be easier if you could share the website link

Comment: i want to, but sadly, it is an intranet website.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.